# grounding wires overkill

Tags: grounding

[image]I have been replacing some light fixture recently and haven't seen any info on connecting grounds wire together with a wire nut when a)one has been grounded to the green screw on the plate and the other one to the box already. Since there was excess on both grounds, I tied them together with a wire nut as a I am a little paranoid that things can come undone on that loosey goosey green screw that doesn't remain still very often and I might need the length in the future, so I chose not to snip. Is this a little overkill or could this make things worse.

thanks,

on the pic the supply ground is attached to the box (cant really see it)

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box?

Comment: Metal boxes are required to be grounded. With solid wire only 1 ground wire under the screw would be legal. If stranded wire and crimp terminals were used more than 1 wire could be under the screw but the standard practice is to use wire nuts. A little extra wire in the box is usually not a problem.

Comment: Why is the green screw loose?  Turn it clockwise and it should tighten.

Comment: as I tighten the screw for some reason it starts to spin back a bit.

Comment: Probably because there's more than one wire on it.  Ground screws are only allowed one wire unless there's a ring terminal on each wire.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have two ground wires: one coming from the cable, and one from the light ballast.

One possible procedure is to twist the two ground wires together, then screw the twisted portion against the fixture.

Alternatively you can screw both wires into the fixture separately, but you will need to find or make a second ground screw.

The fixture should be grounded, so solutions that just connect the two ground wires but do not attach securely to the fixture are not good.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I ended up tightening all the fixture ground and cutting the joined wires. So I have ground to fixture and supply ground to box. One less item to detach in that box is better for me